# Makefile.PL check if source directory found

Tags: perl, makefile, xs, dmake

I am using ExtUtils::MakeMaker to create Makefile.PL
I added the following function to the makefile.PL to check if source directory is exist

```
sub  check_directory  {


my ($argv) = @_;

unless (defined $argv->{'source'} and -d $argv->{'source'}) {


    die 'directory not found ';
}

}
```

now when i run **perl MakeFile.pl --source=/opt/src** everything is ok

but after that whe i run **make/dmake** everything compiles ok but
i am always get the "directory not found " message  and  "Error code 255" any idea why i get it and if there are different way to check if directory found when writting MakeFile.PL worth to mention if i remove the above code the compliation finish with success.

Comment: How do you use the source dir in the generated (made) file?

Comment: in the generated file i get INC => q[-I/opt/src] for the above example

Comment: `-lopt` or `-l/opt`?

Comment: it is  INC => q[-I/opt/src]